# Apply linear transparent gradient to a portion of image with transparent background in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I need to apply linear transparent gradient to only bottom 5% of the image. I have some idea that first I need to create mask on alpha channel. But I'm not sure how I can do that which affects only bottom 5% of the image. I've tried different methods bud no luck so far. The gradient should start at 5% height of the image at 100% alpha and 0% alpha at the end. Also, the images can be non-rectangular PNG with transparent background. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNNJ.png) is an example of what I need. But it can be either a rectangular or non-rectangular image.

Comment: If the gradient is transparent, it won't show. What are you trying to do? Can you show an example of the input and output?  What have you tried? Do you need this in OpenCV or is Python Wand OK? You need to be a bit more clear. Please read the help section of this forum for how to ask a good question and how to provide testable code.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the bottom of the image fade to fully transparent? or perhaps fade to gray?

Comment: See np.linspace() at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html to create a linear gradient

Comment: Hi @fmw42 I have edited and added an example. Please check it out. The bottom of the image should fade to fully transparent. Thank you

Comment: Any library would do. Either opencv, imagemagic, or anything else that can be called through bash terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do that in ImageMagick 7 if you have an existing alpha channel in the input or not. It is slightly different. You basically extract the alpha channel from the input and multiply it with the one containing the gradient. Then put that new one into the original image replacing the existing alpha channel.

Input:

[image]

```
magick lena_circle.png \
-alpha set \
-set option:wd "%w" \
-set option:ht "%h" \
-set option:ht2 "%[fx:round(0.25*ht)]" \
-set option:ht3 "%[fx:ht-ht2]" \
\( -size "%[wd]x%[ht3]" xc:white \) \
\( -size "%[wd]x%[ht2]" gradient:white-black \) \
\( -clone 1,2 -append \) \
-delete 1,2 \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract \) \
\( -clone 1,2 -compose multiply -composite \) \
-delete 1,2 \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
lena_circle_fade3.png
```

Resulting Image:

[image]

Comment: fmw42 - hijacking your answers here as they are incredibly helpful. apologies.
Any chance you have this in python with cv2 as well? trying to decipher it

Comment: van -- sorry, no, I do not have that exact example in OpenCV. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132978/linear-gradient-mask-using-opencv/72133654#72133654 for creating gradient images and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70043154/apply-linear-transparent-gradient-to-a-portion-of-image-with-transparent-backgro/70043309#70043309 for adding a gradient to an image

Comment: appreciate the pointers. Will give it a shot

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy for opaque images.

```
 - Read the input
 - Compute top and bottom heights for the alpha channel
 - Create a constant white image for top
 - Create a vertical gradient going from 255 to 0 for the bottom
 - Stack the top and bottom parts
 - Convert the image to 4 channels BGRA
 - Replace the alpha in the BGRA image with the stacked alpha
 - Save the result
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("lena.png")
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# compute 5% of ht and 95% of ht
# pct = 5
pct = 25    # temparily set pct to 25 percent for demonstration
ht2 = int(ht*pct/100)
ht3 = ht - ht2

# create opaque white image for top
top = np.full((ht3,wd), 255, dtype=np.uint8)

# create vertical gradient for bottom
btm = np.linspace(255, 0, ht2, endpoint=True, dtype=np.uint8)
btm = np.tile(btm, (wd,1))
btm = np.transpose(btm)

# stack top and bottom
alpha = np.vstack((top,btm))

# put alpha channel into image
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = alpha

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_fade.png', result)

# display results
# (note: display does not show transparency)
cv2.imshow('btm', btm)
cv2.imshow('alpha', alpha)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is how to do that in ImageMagick 7.

```
magick lena.png \
-set option:wd "%w" \
-set option:ht "%h" \
-set option:ht2 "%[fx:round(25*ht/100)]" \
-set option:ht3 "%[fx:ht-ht2]" \
\( -size "%[wd]x%[ht3]" xc:white \) \
\( -size "%[wd]x%[ht2]" gradient:white-black \) \
\( -clone 1,2 -append \) \
-delete 1,2 \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
lena_fade2.png
```

Resulting Image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it works for rectangular images only. But not for non-rectangular image. I mean I need to apply this on the images with transparent background. Your code adds black background to the image. Thank you

Comment: I posted another answer that does the fade for images that have transparency or not.

Comment: This is great - and it works great. What if we have an image that already has transparency to it?

Specifically, reading in a buffer with imdecode and IMREAD_COLOR
then converting to RGB

Comment: If the image already has transparency, you need to extract it, then combine it with the gradient transparency (i.e. multiply the two), then put that into the original image in place of its original alpha channel.

Comment: @van -- I have added that Python/OpenCV example as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do that in Python/OpenCV if the image already has transparency. One needs to extract the image alpha, create a new alpha for the gradient and then multiply the two alpha channels together. Finally put the new alpha into the original image replacing the old alpha.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("lena_circ.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# extract the BGR component and the alpha component
bgr_circ = img[:,:,0:3]
alpha_circ = img[:,:,3]

# compute 5% of ht and 95% of ht
# pct = 5
pct = 50    # temparily set pct to 50 percent for demonstration
ht2 = int(ht*pct/100)
ht3 = ht - ht2

# create opaque white image for top
top = np.full((ht3,wd), 255, dtype=np.uint8)

# create vertical gradient for bottom
btm = np.linspace(255, 0, ht2, endpoint=True, dtype=np.uint8)
btm = np.tile(btm, (wd,1))
btm = np.transpose(btm)

# stack top and bottom
alpha = np.vstack((top,btm))

# multiply alpha and alpha_circ
alpha_new = (alpha * alpha_circ.astype(np.float64) / 255).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# put alpha channel into image
result = bgr_circ.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = alpha_new

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_circ_fade.png', result)

# display results
# (note: display does not show transparency)
cv2.imshow('btm', btm)
cv2.imshow('alpha', alpha)
cv2.imshow('alpha_circ', alpha_circ)
cv2.imshow('alpha_new', alpha_new)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]