# Linear Gradient Mask using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

First of all, sorry for my bad english. The answer to the question here is definitely the answer I was looking for [Creating a Linear Gradient Mask using opencv or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444510/creating-a-linear-gradient-mask-using-opencv-or?newreg=d5a40e601d4c448bb89e60449cbf2968) but I want to make this strip vertical. How can I do that? @HansHirse

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't know how to ask in simpler way. I want to make the black and white strip vertical.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my question. I created a third mask called mask3 and I equated it to np.rot90(mask1)

```
mask3 = np.rot90(mask1)
```

Comment: Your did not say in your question that you already had a horizontal ramp. I though you wanted to create them from scratch. Please be more specific in your question with code and example images. Read the help file on this forum about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make both horizontal and vertical linear gradient image in Python/OpenCV/Numpy. The difference is whether the transpose operation is inside or outside the tile operation.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# horizontal gradient ramp
ramp_width = 500
ramp_height = 200
ramp = np.linspace(0, 255, ramp_width, dtype=np.uint8)
ramp_horizontal = np.tile(np.transpose(ramp), (ramp_height,1))
ramp_horizontal = cv2.merge([ramp_horizontal,ramp_horizontal,ramp_horizontal])
cv2.imshow("horizontal_ramp", ramp_horizontal)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("horizontal_ramp.jpg", ramp_horizontal)

# vertical gradient ramp
ramp_width = 200
ramp_height = 500
ramp = np.linspace(0, 255, ramp_height, dtype=np.uint8)
ramp_vertical = np.transpose(np.tile(ramp, (ramp_width,1)))
cv2.merge([ramp_vertical,ramp_vertical,ramp_vertical])
cv2.imshow("vertical_ramp", ramp_vertical)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("vertical_ramp.jpg", ramp_vertical)
```

Horizontal Ramp:

[image]

Vertical Ramp:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How should I modify the code to achieve such a transition?
![Linear Gradient](https://i.imgur.com/kH7dEZJ.png).

Comment: Apply a power law less than 1, for example 0.5 (e.g. square root) to my result. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dfe/group__intensity__transform.html#gaec85454c2cd29f2440fefd55d609e682